# Finding cause and effect correlation in a dataset

Tags: python, correlation

What methods might one use in order to find and analyze cause-and-effect in a dataset? An example might be something like plotting this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

n1 = np.array([100, 100, 150, 150, 150, 100, 100, 100, 100])
n2 = np.array([100, 100, 100, 100, 120, 120, 120, 100, 100])

plt.plot(n1, label="feature1")
plt.plot(n2, label="feature2")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Where we see that some causal happens at feature 1, and a number of iterations later, feature2 experiences some sort of effect. The scales may be different, the iterations may bee slightly different, but looking at it on a graph like this, it appears that they are correlated by some sort of cause-and-effect.

Is there any way that one would be able to programmatically identify something like this? Or maybe give it a score of how correlated through cause-and-effect they might be?

Comment: Your conclusions are wrong I'm afraid: by itself a graph like this doesn't show causation, the two features could represent anything and happen to be this way by chance. Even if there was external information available, there's no reason to think that feature 1 causes feature 2 just because feature 1 happens "before" feature 2, for instance there could be an unknown variable "causing" both of them. For instance poverty causes poor health and high criminality, but poor health doesn't cause criminality.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, I wasn't going into specifics enough for the dataset I was using. In the case of my dataset, there is clear cause and effect. And I was just showing an example of what the two features might look like when plotted out.

Comment: Ok, if causation is already established and the goal is to measure how strongly feature 1 and 2 are related, then there's a lot of options but it depends on the nature of these features. Simple correlation would say if the trend is similar, [DTW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) could be used to measure the similarity of the curves, and there are probably other options as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifying correlation in data is possible with standard statistical tools, and it can be done programmatically. Correlation requires a representative sample, so in a case like the single graph that you show it wouldn't work: you'd probably need at least 20-30 such graphs in order to have a chance to confidently show correlation.

Identifying causation (cause and effect) is much harder. To the best of my knowledge it cannot be done from raw data without any additional knowledge. This is simply because with any dataset, there's no way to know if some external variable plays a causative role in the observations.

The way causation is proved is through a specific experimental setting, i.e. it's **the design of the experiment** which allows collecting data susceptible to prove causation. [A/B testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) is a method used for this kind of experiment. Example: suppose we want to test whether new drug A has an effect on outcome B. Design the experiment to observe the response variable B on a representative sample of patients. Randomly split the sample into two subsets: the first one is the control group, they are given a placebo. The second is given drug A. At the end of the experiment one can prove causation if and only if the second group shows a significantly different outcome compared to the control group.